# The method setActionBar(Toolbar) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (Toolbar)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

This is the XML for the Toolbar layout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I'm using the support library to use a Toolbar as my ActionBar. I did this in onCreate...

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toolbar, null);
setActionBar(mToolbar);
```

But if gives me the red squigglies and tells me that message in the title. I'm like, LULWUT?!

Comment: I tried inflate the layout to a View first then getting the toolbar from that view using findViewById, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 10):

You probably need [`setSupportActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)) instead. Using the `Toolbar` means you should be using `AppCompatActivity`, and all this stuff lives in the appcompat (~support) library.

Edit: this answer still applies if you are using the now-deprecated `ActionBarActivity`, since [`ActionBarActivity` inherits the `setSupportActionBar` method from `AppCompactActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html).

Answer (score 2):

**2019 UPDATE**

According to API 29, Toolbar is now in package `androidx.appcompat.widget`. So, in the layout file:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

In Java code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
...
setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
```